# Converting Dataframe to LIST

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I wish to convert a dataframe to list. Here's an example dataframe:

```
colname   name    age    address
1         John    22     Singapore
2         James   44     India
3         Jessie  21     Australia
```

I would like to convert it to a list like:

```
Name : John Age: 22 Address: Singapore
Name : James Age: 44 Address India
Name : Jessie Age: 21 Address: Australia.
```

So basically I wish to get an aggregate of column name and corresponding value of the row in a single R datatype.

`as.list` didn't work for me.

Comment: are you looking to convert this to JSON?

Comment: `lapply(split(X, rownames(X)), as.list)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can simply use:

```
 apply(X, 1, function(r) paste(names(X), r, sep=":", collapse=" "))
```

*where `X` is your `data.frame`*

If you do not want the first column in the output, add the appropriate `[, -1]` and `[-1]` respectively:

```
apply(X[, -1], 1, function(r) paste(names(X)[-1], r, sep=":", collapse=" "))

[1] "name:John age:22 address:Singapore"  
[2] "name:James age:44 address:India"     
[3] "name:Jessie age:21 address:Australia"
```

---

However, if your goal is to get this into JSON, you can use the `rjson` package:

```
library(rjson)
apply(X[,-1], 1, toJSON)
```

Which would give you an appropriately quoted string:

```
cat( apply(X[,-1], 1, toJSON) )

{"name":"John","age":"22","address":"Singapore"} 
{"name":"James","age":"44","address":"India"}
{"name":"Jessie","age":"21","address":"Australia"}
```

Comment: Hey Ricardo, Thanks for a quick reply.
Basically what I am trying to do is insert a data frame in mongodb, but the rmongodb package that I am using wants list or bson like object to be passed. 
example: mongo.insert(mongo,"collection name",list\bson object)

I am a newbie to both R and Mongo so my apologies if my doubts would be too simple.

Comment: no prob.  `rjson` should give you an output that is accetable to mongo.  Also, have you looked at [the RMongo package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMongo/index.html), is that what you are using now ?

Comment: No I am using http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmongodb/rmongodb.pdf package.

Comment: I have to convert this to a list and then try to convert the list to a BSON object using a function in the package. But what I have understood of list so far is that when you convert a dataframe to list using as.list function what you get is a list of element on the grounds of column and not rows, correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: Also, there are at least three mongo/R packages.  If one doesnt work, hit google and try another

Comment: apply(X, 1, as.list) worked perfect,  converted that to a BSON :) Thanks a lot bro... Cheers